# VTK: how to move clipped output (periodic boundary conditions)

Tags: c++, vtk, clipping, bounding-box

I have some objects (spheres or cubes or something else) and I want to cut them when the protude out of my bounding-box and put the cut off part back in the szene on the opposit side of the bounding-box.

Cutting the objects works fine and storeing the cut of parts works fine too.

But I do not know how i can move them, apart from checking every possible position (cut at the x-axis, cut at the x- and the y-axis, ....) with mass-if-statements...

Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you give us an example to work from?

Comment: I have a bounding-box (a cube) from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) and I have a cube in the scene, with center at (0,0.5,0.5) and edge-length 0.5.
I want now to cut the cube at the bounding box and put the cut of part back in the scene but translated about (1,0,0) so he comes in form the other side of the bounding-box

Comment: in 2D i want to go from the left picture to the right one:
http://gbimg.org/p.php?q=6EtXy

Comment: So you are looking to implement *periodic boundary conditions* (it may be worth altering your title or description to include that). It would still be helpful to supply the code that draws your cube, to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: ok, I changed the titel. Thanks so far, but I havn't found a better way then cutting every object with every cube-plane and create a second one, which is moved to the other side of the cube, and clip the whole scene